# Is it possible to use Active Directory Graph Api without consent?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm looking at the sample codes at
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console

It seems no matter we get the AD client for application or user, it will need the user's consent. Is it possible that we can use the graph api without user's consent considering the user can provide client id or any other password/secrect?

I'm working on the project which is supposed to run as a windows service in the background. If it needs a consent once a while, then we probably can not use windows service for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No , adding a delegated permission to an application does not automatically grant consent to the users within the tenant. The users must still manually consent for the added delegated permissions at runtime, unless the administrator clicks the `Grant Permissions` button from the `Required Permissions` section of the application page in the Azure portal to do the admin consent . In that code sample , if you choose running the console app in app mode , an admin user will need to consent for the application permissions .

Please click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview#understanding-user-and-admin-consent) for more details about user and admin consent .

In your scenario , you can use [Client Credentials Grant Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service) which permits a web service (confidential client) to use its own credentials instead of impersonating a user . After adding permissions for Azure AD Graph api , click the `Grant Permissions` button from the `Required Permissions` section of the application page in the Azure portal with admin account . After admin consent , you can acquire token for Graph API using app's identity and won't asked to consent at runtime . [Code samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-code-samples#server-or-daemon-application-to-web-api) using client credential flow are for your reference  .

Answer (score 0):

As [@Nan Yu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5751404/nan-yu) said , you can use  admin account of your directory to reach the **Grant permissions**. Also, there is another solution for your case. It’s in the bottom of the link which you post. I tried it in my test lab and it worked. The solution is here:

If you want to run the console app in app mode (which is somewhat contrived, since this really should be run as a native client), you'll need to force consent manually, beforehand. Here, an admin user will need to consent. You can force consent by opening a browser, and going to the following URL, replacing `tenantId` with your **tenantId**, and `app-mode-application-id` with your **Application ID** for your app mode application:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/oauth2/authorize?client_id=app-mode-application-id>&response_type=code &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F&response_mode=query   &resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net%2F&state=12345
```

After signing in (if not already signed in), click the **Accept** in the consent page. You can then close the browser. Now that you've **pre-consented,** you can try running the console sample in app mode.

Comment: Hi, @urlreader , If this answer can be helpful to you , please mark it as an answer to help more people. Thanks!